# Transforming Hough Image to different origin in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm using the image processing toolbox implementation of the Hough transform in Matlab.

It works well, but it puts the origin at the upper left corner of the image and that results in an unnecessarily large Hough image with a lot of unused space.

I would like to do the Hough transform with the origin at the center of the image so the radius range will be reduces. Also it is required for an algorithm I'm implementing to have the Hough space represented in this way.

I don't want to implement the Hough transform from scratch because I don't know mex well enough to re-implement it as efficiently as Matlab. So I've been trying to take the hough transform Matlab does and transform the hough image in some way to effectively move the origin afterwards.

Anyone know an easier way or how to do as I suggested?

Comment: Couldn't you just subtract the distance from the corner of the image to the center from all the radii?

Comment: Not quite that simple. Imagine a vertical line through the center of the image. The Radius from the matlab hough of that line would be half the image width, but the Radius from a centered hough transform would be 0. Picture similar simple cases for horizontal lines, 45 degree angles, and you see that the shift varies with theta

Comment: You're right - oops. But, you could feasibly reparameterize with respect to the center coordinates though. You could recalculate 'r' using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line and then recalculate the angle. I don't know the most efficient way to implement this but it would be much much easier to take this approach than to re-implement the hough.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this idea isn't really precise in my mind yet but here's a couple ideas I came up with:

a) You can either reparamterize the radii and angles with respect to the center of the image. This shouldn't be too hard but you'd have to think about it a little bit.

b) You can try something like this:
[image]

You can take the `hough` of each of the four quadrants of the images. If you do the regular `hough` on the "D", then the accumulator should automatically be correct. Taking the `hough` of "B" would require you to do a `flipud` before taking the `hough`. Afterwards the radius would be correct but the angle would need to be flipped over the horizontal axis. After doing a similar method on all four quadrants and fixing the angles, you can just add the accumulators together and then find where the lines are located.

If I have time I think I might try to implement this myself just to see how it works. From the documentation it appears you can't directly do this with the `hough` provided by matlab so these two solutions are the best I can think of off the top of my head. Maybe someone else will post something easier though.

Comment: I like this approach, if I have time later I'll see if it works